# Google Doc - how to remove the header while using it in iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-document-viewer

How to remove or hide this header section: (zoom in , out, page number, back, next, popup)

[image]

while using this method:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.webiste.com/pdffiles.pdf&embedded=true" 
style="width:750px; height:5190px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to target each element in javascript and hide them.

```
function hideelements() {
     document.getElementById('element id which you want to hide').style.dispaly = 'none';
}
```

This is javascript code which will help you. you have to call function on loading event so it will hide your elemenets.

Comment: But that toolbar is inside an iframe, so how can you from main page go inside the iframe and hide it? also the iframe is browsing external web URL (some browser security reason do not allow iframe modification if the URL is not local URL)